# multiple columns to XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given two tables:

`T1( EntityID int , EmailAddress varchar(55),MaxNumberOfConnections int )`

`T2( EntityID int , EntityAttributes XML )`

How do I insert all the data from `T1` into `T2` with a single statement in such a way that all the columns in `T1` (all but `EntityID` ) are converted into one XML column in `T2` :

```
T1( 1,'1234@1234.com',454)

T2(1, '<Attributes>
          <Attribute EmailAddress="1234@1234.com">
          <Attribute MaxNumberOfConnections ="454">
      </Attributes>' )
```

Comment: Does the XML need to be in exactly that format? By reusing the element Attribute, but using different attributes, you're providing a different definition for the same name.  Could you combine into a single Attribute element with multiple attributes (for the fields), or use an element for EmailAddress, MaxNumberOfConnections, etc?

Comment: XML schema doesn't have to be exactly as the one I show here.

Comment: Then post your exact schema, how then you expect to get an accurrate answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions based upon my comment - 
Single "Attribute" element with multiple attributes:

```
SELECT
    EntityId,
    (
        SELECT
            EmailAddress AS [Attribute/@EmailAddress],
            MaxNumberOfConnections AS [Attribute/@MaxNumberOfConnections]
        FROM
            T1 i
        WHERE
            i.EntityId = o.EntityId
        FOR XML PATH('Attributes')
    ) AS EntityAttributes 
FROM
    T1 o
```

Individual element for each field:

```
SELECT
    EntityId,
    (
        SELECT
            EmailAddress,
            MaxNumberOfConnections
        FROM
            T1 i
        WHERE
            i.EntityId = o.EntityId
        FOR XML PATH('Attributes')
    ) AS EntityAttributes 
FROM
    T1 o
```